# Does a bounded service destroyed when all activites unbind it?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am creating a separate thread in a android bounded service's onStartCommand() and running it using a condition check in Runnable's Run() e.g. while (condition), there is a activity which is using this bounded service and then unbound it. I read that there is a rule that bounded services automatically destroyed if there is no activity bound to it. Do I need to flip my condition in unbind method otherwise how service will know that it must terminate now ? If yes, then its controlled by my code not by Android itself

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class ServiceDemo extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "ServiceDemo";

    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private boolean isBound = false;
    private int counter = 0;
    private static final int MIN = 0;
    private static final int MAX = 100;

    IBinder myServiceBinder = new MyServiceBinder();

    public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public ServiceDemo getServiceInstance(){
            return ServiceDemo.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        isBound = true;
        return myServiceBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand executed in Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        isRunning = true;
        generateSequentialInteger(MIN, MAX);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void generateSequentialInteger(int start, int stop){
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               counter = start;
               while(isRunning && counter<stop){
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   Log.i(TAG, "Thread ID : "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" : Service has generated number "+counter);
                   counter++;
               }
           }
       }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind executed");
        isBound = false;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy executed");
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: Yes, if all activities unbind from a service that is not running in the foreground, the service will be killed (destroyed) by the framework.

Comment: small FYI, you should return true from `onUnbind` and override `onRebind` to raise your `isBound` flag as well.

Comment: thanks ....Still my doubt is not cleared. Do I need to stop the thread manually on unBind event ? If Yes, what happens when multiple services are bound to this ? Also is implementation for onBind() and onUnbound is correct  ? Because it seems this might not work when multiple activities bound and unBound with this service ?